# How do i dynamically change file-names with Rename-Item?

Tags: powershell, rename-item-cmdlet

I'm trying to use the cmdlet `Rename-Item` to change the file name of multiple files in a folder. 
This is an example of my files (*there are more files in reality*):

```
1_File1.sql
1_File2.sql
1_File3.sql
2_File4.sql
3_File5_NOT_DONE.sql
3_File6_NOT_DONE.sql
3_File7_NOT_DONE.sql
3_File8_NOT_DONE.sql
4_File9_NOT_DONE.sql
5_File10_NOT_DONE.sql
6_File11.sql
6_File12.sql
```

What I wan't to do is remove the **_NOT_DONE** part from these files:

```
3_File5_NOT_DONE.sql
3_File6_NOT_DONE.sql
3_File7_NOT_DONE.sql
3_File8_NOT_DONE.sql
```

*e.g. the files starting with **3_File***

I wan't the complete list to look like this when I'm done:

```
1_File1.sql
1_File2.sql
1_File3.sql
2_File4.sql
3_File5.sql
3_File6.sql
3_File7.sql
3_File8.sql
4_File9_NOT_DONE.sql
5_File10_NOT_DONE.sql
6_File11.sql
6_File12.sql
```

I have tried using this in powershell and it gets all the files, but it forces me to set the new names to a static name (see the last part of the `-Replace`):

```
Get-ChildItem *.sql | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -Replace '3_File.*_NOT_DONE\.sql$', '<static filename>.sql'}
```

I would like to use regular expressions in the last part of `-Replace` as well. Or maybe there is another way to make the new names keep a part of their original name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this would help you:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem 3_*.sql | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace "_NOT_DONE", ""}
```

Before: "3_File8_NOT_DONE.sql

After: "3_File8.sql"

Comment: This only removes the `_NOT_DONE`-part from the one file starting with `3_File8`. I need it to do exacly this but for all of the files starting with `3_File` followed anything and ending with `.sql`. So that it will hit `3_File5`, `3_File6`, `3_File7` and `3_File8`.

Comment: Okay I think I get it: `Get-ChildItem 3_*.sql  | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace "_NOT_DONE", ""}` So every File starting with "3_" will be renamed.

Comment: That's right! Looks so obvious now when I see it. Edit that into your answer and I'll put as the accepted answer :)

Comment: Trivial fun fact.  Replacing with a null is optional.   `{$_.Name -replace "_NOT_DONE"}`

Answer (score 2):

To get you desired list, it would work with this solution

```
Get-ChildItem C:\temp\test\3*.sql | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace "_NOT_DONE", ""}
```

Note that you filter Get-ChildItem so that only the files are renamed when they start with a "3" and end as ".sql".
The solution from @Lndngr would remove the "_NOT_DONE" from all files.

Comment: Sorry this is right too, but I can only choose one. You can have my upvote though :)